# How do I create a single.php for a specific category?

Tags: wpdb, single

I am trying to create a single.php file for a specific category on my site. Instead of loading the single.php file I want WP to return that category in a file called single-category-53.php (the actual category id=53). I allow the selection of multiple categories on the site, and with the help of Hikari's permalink plugin, we choose the appropriate category for the permalink. Because of this I can't reference any built in functions for categories as Wordpress defaults to a numerical order. The code below works through the if ($catp == 53)... I've verified that. The issue seems to be in calling the single-category-53.php file, or I'm improperly doing the nested if statement.

I have verified that I uploaded the single-category-53.php file to the child theme directory.

Any help in correction of the code is appreciated!

```
    // A function which displays a specific catergory equal to the _category_permalink

    function ag_templates($single_template) {

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta" ;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$table}
                              WHERE `post_id` = %d 
                              AND `meta_key` LIKE '_category_permalink' ",
                              $post->ID );
    $perma = $wpdb->get_row( $query );
    $catp = $perma->meta_value;
    if ($catp == 53) {
    if ( file_exists (STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-53.php") ) 
    $single_template = STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-53.php"; }
    return $single_template;
    }

    add_filter( "single_template", "ag_templates" ) ;

    // End specific category template function.
```

Comment: I'm confused. you want a particular single template to be used if the post is in a specific category? is it the case that sometimes a post is in that category but you don't want that specific single template used?

Comment: I'm trying to save myself from having to edit 50,000+ posts... :-) We could simply remove the multiple categories and use just one (the one we now permalink). But basically what you're saying is what I need, it would resolve us from having to edit those posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
function ag_templates( $template = '' ){
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_category_permalink', true );
    if( 53 == $meta ){
        $template = locate_template(
            array( "single-category-53.php", $template ),
            false
        );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'ag_templates' );
```

Comment: Milo... you nailed it. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you need it done that way, but if the way doesn't matter too much to you. Here's what I would do.

1. Create a file called e.g. mycat-term.php
2. Use a condition to find that category you'r looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax
3. If that condition then is true I call my file from step one http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Put this code in your single.php:

```
if ( is_category( 'term_you_are_looking_for' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'mycat', 'term' ); // gets mycat-term.php
}
```

Update: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to acomplish but since you are on single.php and the categories/tags aren't directly available here are a couple more snippets that can help you get them there.

```
global $post;
$current_tax = get_post_taxonomies($post->ID); // get current taxonomies array: [0] = cat, [1] = tag    
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $current_tax[1]);
$term = $terms->taxonomy;`
```

You can reference the taxonomy the in the $args for the get_category(); function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: Marcup... doesn't your system only work if the page is an archive page? I'm not trying to display a template for an archive page... this is a template for the posts within a specific category. It replaces the single.php for that category only.

Comment: Just updated above.

Comment: I think your solution would work well marcup if it wasn't for the selection of multiple categories. Since I select a primary category from the multiple categories, I only want to display the page when the category I selected is primary... hence the reason for the call to wpdb.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got for you right now.