# Create single.php for specific category by category id

Tags: categories, customization, templates, single

I'm trying to create template for specific category with id 1 for example.
The template should be applied to all of the pages belongs to this category.
So, it should be something like single-1.php.

I tried a lot of solution that I found on the web, [including this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84537/how-do-i-create-a-single-php-for-a-specific-category), but it seems nothing is works for me.

Comment: Or you could use just the single.php and in the contents, you adjust based on an if statement (i.e. `<?php if ( in_category(20) ) { ?>`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to add category specific single template pages on your website. This goes in `functions.php`

You can define as many single templates as you want.

```
function wpse_category_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;
    $all_cats = get_the_category();

    if ( $all_cats[0]->cat_ID == '1' ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_template_directory() . "/single-cat1.php") ) return get_template_directory() . "/single-cat1.php";
    } elseif ( $all_cats[0]->cat_ID == '2' ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_template_directory() . "/single-cat2.php") ) return get_template_directory() . "/single-cat2.php";
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_category_single_template' );
```

Here I used `single-cat1.php` for category id 1 and `single-cat2.php` for category id 2. You can name these single templates as you feel right.

This function also uses default fallback to `single.php` if there is no `single-cat1.php` or `single-cat2.php` exists.

**EDIT 1**

I have been using above code on 2 of my websites and it's working fine on latest version of WordPress.

Paste this in your `functions.php`

```
function show_template() {
    global $template;
    print_r($template);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'show_template' );
```

This will print the template file used on each page/post. Now access your website and see if correct template file is being used or not? If it's still showing `single.php` then there is something wrong with your code.

**EDIT 2**

Here is your code for that.

```
function wpse_category_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;
    $all_cats = get_the_category();

    if ( in_category(6) ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_template_directory() . "/page-custom.php") ) {
          return get_template_directory() . "/page-custom.php";
        } else {
          return get_template_directory() . "/page.php";
        }
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_category_single_template' );
```

Comment: Don't use `TEMPLATEPATH`. See [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298)

Comment: And better use [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) instead of "if file_exists() then return"

Comment: @PieterGoosen just made that change. Although ticket says `TEMPLATEPATH` is deprecate but it does not show any warnings in WordPress. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks guys!
I tried to apply this code and it still not works for me.

After I add this function to my function.php
and defined the single-cat.php, the related pages (with same cat ID) remained unchanged with the basic single.php template. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Netsh Please check edit in my answer. And also if you still have issue, [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/168754/edit) and post your code that you added in your `functions.php`.

Comment: Hi. it was great idea! thanks! now I see that I should define category template to page.php and not to single.php. what should i change So that the code will work me?

Comment: It should be something like this:  - if page category id is 6 -use page-custom.php, else, use -page.php

Comment: @Netsh colud you check my code? This code can not work, because Robert assume checked category is first witch was assign. This is wrong. Why if cat_ID 1 is third element of $all_cats?

Comment: @Netsh please check `Edit 2` for your exact answer.

Comment: @Roberthue your code is wrong... What if category object with cat_ID == 6 is in $all_cats with index [1]? What if $all_cat[0]->cat_ID == 6 is false but $all_cat[1]->cat_ID is true?

Comment: Well, first of all thanks. I'm appreciating your help! I tried this code and it is still doesn't work for me. it look like that the system does not recognize this function, and the default page.php style appear..

Comment: @Netsh try the last code again and let me know, added marcin's suggestion. It should work because I have been using it on 2 of my website without any issue. Also make sure that any other function should not overwrite it's code/effect.

Comment: Sorry.. doesn't work for me.. but thank you all for the efforts.. I check my other functions.php and I didn't find any problematic function.. I will try in other direction..
Thanks again.

Comment: Why not use `in_category()` or `has_category()` to test a post for a specific category attached ;-)

Comment: I tried this code. I found that get_template_directory() gets the parent theme, not the child theme. So, it can't find the new template file.

Answer (score 2):

Use filter [single_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) to change template file and function [in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) to check is this post in category.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'my_single_template' );
function my_single_template($single_template)
{
    if (in_category(1)) {
        $file = get_template_directory().'/single-cat-1.php';
        if ( file_exists($file) ) {
            return $file;
        }
    }
    return $single_template;
}
```

Comment: Could I get a feedback? What is wrong with my answer? If you downvote please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `single_template` filter, `in_category()` condition and the queried object to test if the current post is attached to our specified category and if so, include our desired template

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current single post
    $post_id = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id();

    // Test to see if our post belongs to category 1
    if ( !in_category( 1, $post_id ) ) {
        return $template;
    }

    // Our post is attached to category 1, lets look for single-1.php
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'single-1.php' );

    // Test if our template exist, if so, include it, otherwise bail
    if ( !$locate_template ) {
        return $template;
    }

    return $locate_template;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning that if you are using a child theme then use the following code to retrieve category single post template.

```
function wpse_category_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;
    $all_cats = get_the_category();
    if ( $all_cats[0]->slug == 'cat1' ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-cat1.php") ) return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-cat1.php";
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_category_single_template' );
```