# Custom Category Archive Pages

Tags: categories, archives

I have a WP installation with 6 categories and I want 3 of them to use a custom Category Archive Page called "category-special.php" (default page is the "category.php").
I found the code below that looks to be close to my query, how can I modify and make it work for me, so categories 31,40 and 55 to load the above specific page?

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpsites_photo_page_template', 99 );
function wpsites_photo_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_category('33') ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'photo.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: check below thread<br>
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168754/create-single-php-for-specific-category-by-category-id

Comment: well I want to have different template for the category archive page ONLY not for the pages under the category

Answer (score 0):

you can use the category-slug.php file name if you want to have a custom page for each  category

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates  here is a link that will help you.

Comment: I know that but I want to have 3 categories with the same page layout and another 3 with other, so it is not practical.

Comment: That can be done with a if statement so like if catagrery name is 33 the load cateagry-33.php elseif catagery name is 34 then load categery-34.php

Comment: same problem here as a I have to create 3 different files with the same content

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code :

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpsites_photo_page_template', 99 );
function wpsites_photo_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_category('31') || is_category('40') || is_category('55') ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'photo.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```